# Is there a simpler form that could replace new ActionListener()?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In order to create a number of buttons with a one-liner like:

```
val buttonPanel = new JPanel()
buttonPanel.add(makeButton("Action #1", myEventListener.doActionOne))
buttonPanel.add(makeButton("Action #2", myEventListener.doActionTwo))
buttonPanel.add(makeButton("Action #3", myEventListener.doActionThree))
```

I created this method `makeButton`:

```
def makeButton(title: String, callback: () => Unit) = {
  val button = new JButton(title)
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent): Unit = callback()})
  button
}
```

Intellij flags `new ActionListener()` with a warning, and offers to change it. Allowing the change results in:

```
def makeButton(title: String, callback: () => Unit) = {
  val button = new JButton(title)
  button.addActionListener((e: ActionEvent) => callback())
  button
}
```

This results in an unused variable `e`, but more importantly, it results in this error at runtime:

```
Error:(90, 47) type mismatch;
 found   : java.awt.event.ActionEvent => Unit
 required: java.awt.event.ActionListener
    button.addActionListener((e: ActionEvent) => callback())
```

Is there a simplification here that could be applied manually, or that Intellij could apply?

Comment: What's the warning? And what happens if you ascribe the type explicitly: `button.addActionListener(((e: ActionEvent) => callback()): ActionListener)`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - It says, "Convert expression to Single Abstract Method." Not a code warning, but stylistic. I care because it's an opportunity to learn if there's a more idiomatic way this could be coded.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - scalac gives a type mismatch error: Error:(94, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : java.awt.event.ActionEvent => Unit
 required: java.awt.event.ActionListener
    button.addActionListener(((e: ActionEvent) => callback()): ActionListener)

Comment: Isn't it an indication that IJ simply expects from scalac something that scalac does not support (maybe it's 2.11.something and `-Xexperimental` is not activated)? I can't quite reproduce it on 2.12.4 (without any extra-flags), it just compiles nicely with `b.addActionListener((e: ActionEvent) => print("blah"))` and runs without any errors...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - That sounds like a good explanation of what's going on. We're constrained to 2.11 since this is code that runs in Spark on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work ?

```
def makeButton(title: String, callback: () => Unit) = {
  val button = new JButton(title)
  val listener: ActionListener = (e: ActionEvent) => callback()
  button.addActionListener(listener)
  button
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this actually results in the same error at runtime.